# Vector field $V$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ $\pi$-related to vector field on $\mathbb{RP}^n$ iff $V_{tx} = tV_x$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, vector-fields

Let $\pi : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ be the projection. Let $V$ be a (smooth) vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$. Show that $V$ is $\pi$-related to a vector field on $\mathbb{RP}^n$ if and only if $V_{tx} = tV_x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$
and $t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

My first thought is that this has something to to with the fact that $tx$ and $x$ are mapped by $\pi$ to the same element. We assume that $V$ is $\pi$-related to a vector field $W$ on $\mathbb{RP}^n$, i.e.

$T_\pi\circ V=W\circ\pi$,

where $T_\pi$ is the tangent map. Hence we have that

$T_\pi\circ V_{tx}=W\circ\pi(tx)=W\circ\pi(x)=T_\pi\circ V_x$,

i.e.

$V_{tx}(\cdot\circ\pi)=V_x(\cdot\circ\pi)$,

where $V_{tx}$ and $V_x$ are derivations on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Does this get me any closer to the goal? What can I do from here?

Please tell me if I should add more information. Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$It looks to me that $V(tx) = tV(x)$ is sufficient but not necessary: If $V$ is $\pi$-related to a vector field on $\Reals\Proj^{n}$, and if $V'$ is an arbitrary radial field, then $V + V'$ is $\pi$-related to a vector field on $\Reals\Proj^{n}$ since $\pi_{*}V' = 0$.

Anyway, you're thinking along productive lines (no pun), but need a bit more than the fact that $x$ and $tx$ map to the same point under $\pi$. It probably helps to write the multiplicative action of the group of non-zero reals on $X = \Reals^{n+1} \setminus \{0\}$ as mappings:
$$
f_{t}(x) = tx.
$$
Then $\pi = \pi \circ f_{t}$ for all $t \neq 0$, and $(f_{t})_{*}(x, v) = (tx, tv)$ for all $(x, v)$ in $TX$.

The claim is, a vector field $V$ on $X$ is $\pi$-related to a vector field on $\Reals\Proj^{n}$ if and only if $\pi_{*}V = \pi_{*}(f_{t})_{*}V$, if and only if $\pi_{*}V(tx) = t\pi_{*}V(x)$.

Comment: Is what you're saying that the "only if" part cannot be proven? To show the other direction of the implication, I want to define the vector field $W$ on $\mathbb{RP}^n$ by $W([x])=T\pi\circ V_x$. Since $T\pi\circ V_{tx}=T\pi(tV_x)=T\pi\circ Tf_t\circ V_x=T(\pi\circ f_t)\circ V_x=T\pi\circ V_x$, it follows that $W$ is well-defined. But how can I show that it is smooth?

Comment: 1. Yes, "only if" is not correct as stated, e.g., $V(x) = x/\|x\|$ does not satisfy $V(tx) = tV(x)$, but is $\pi$-related to the zero field. 2. For smoothness of $W$, it's enough to work in an affine chart where one homogeneous coordinate is $1$. :)